# Make test with Jest on my serverless application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, aws-serverless

I have a serverless application and I want to make unit test on it

I know there is a serverless plugin for Jest but I use classic Jest for now.

I have a function like this in a **tools.js** file

```js
const ddb = require('./ddb');
const table = process.env.USER_TABLE;

...

module.exports.mailExist = async email => {
  if (!email) {
    throw new Error('Missing parameters');
  }
  return await ddb.scan({
    TableName: table,
    FilterExpression: 'email = :email',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':email': email
    },
    ProjectionExpression: ['uid']
  });
};
```

And I would like to test it in a **__test__/tools.test.js** file

```
describe('mailExist', async () => {
    const email = 'example@example.com';
    const mailExist = await tools.mailExist(email)
    it('should not exist', () => {
        expect(mailExist).toBe({})
    })
});
```

The problem is, when I run my test, it return

> Missing required key 'TableName' in params

because my 'table' variable is an environment variable

And if I write my table name since of the environment variable, it return

> Missing region in config

So my question is, I would like to know how can I test my function of my serverless application in a specific file and how can I pass my AWS configuration to my function?

If you have questions, tell me

Thank you

PS : my scan function in ddb file looks like this

```
//ddb.js

module.exports.scan = async params => {
    const result = await DynamoDB.scan(params).promise();
    return result.Items;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a unit test solution:

`tools.js`:

```js
const ddb = require('./ddb');

const table = process.env.TableName;

module.exports.mailExist = async email => {
  if (!email) {
    throw new Error('Missing parameters');
  }
  return await ddb.scan({
    TableName: table,
    FilterExpression: 'email = :email',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':email': email
    },
    ProjectionExpression: ['uid']
  });
};
```

`tools.spec.js`, you should set the environment variable firstly before requiring the `tools.js`. We store the original `TableName` environment variable to a variable, and restore the environment variables after all unit tests are done.

```js
const ddb = require('./ddb');

describe('mailExist', () => {
  const TableName = process.env.TableName;
  const fakeTableName = 'fake table name';
  beforeAll(() => {
    process.env.TableName = fakeTableName;
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    process.env.TableName = TableName;
  });

  test('should not exist', async () => {
    const tools = require('./tools');
    const email = 'example@example.com';
    const scanSpy = jest.spyOn(ddb, 'scan').mockResolvedValueOnce({});
    const actualValue = await tools.mailExist(email);
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({});
    expect(scanSpy).toBeCalledWith({
      TableName: fakeTableName,
      FilterExpression: 'email = :email',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':email': email
      },
      ProjectionExpression: ['uid']
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/58727351/tools.spec.js
  mailExist
    ✓ should not exist (112ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |       80 |    66.67 |    66.67 |       75 |                   |
 ddb.js   |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 3 |
 tools.js |     87.5 |    66.67 |      100 |    83.33 |                 7 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.095s, estimated 8s
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've used your code, but i have a last problem. scanSpy isn't call with the fakeTableName, it's call with TableName variable

Comment: @dc-mpo The example works fine. I guess you are using `dotenv` module to load the environment variables from `.env`, it will affect the test result. And, I don't know how you use `process.env.TableName ` environment variables in your `tools.js` file. You can edit your question, add more information.

Comment: I've edit my question, i've had the beginning of my script, where I call my environment variables for mailExist

And yes, I use dotenv with a **jest.config.js** file where I export a setup file in which I do `require("dotenv").config()`

Comment: I've understand why it not works for me, it's because I create my constant TableName outside of the function, i create it at the beginning of my file

Thanks for your help, you've get me out of a tight spot :)